# class-scoped enum in class template

Tags: c++, templates, forward-declaration

Let's say I have a class `Person`, and subclasses `Teacher` and `Lawyer`.

There is also a class `Tool`, and subclasses `TeacherTool:Tool` and `LawyerTool:Tool`.

Now, each `Person` has `Tool`'s, and `Tool` has a function `getToolUses` which returns an enum `Usage`. i.e:

```
enum Usage;
Person{
 Tool *Tools[];
}
Tool{
 Usage getToolUses();
}

Teacher:public Person{}
TeacherTool: public Tool{
 TeacherUsage getToolUses();
}
// etc Lawyer
```

Now, you can't override function return types in C++, but you *can* use a template class to change the return type, like so:

```
Person{
 Tool *Tools[];
}

template <class Usage>
Tool{
 virtual Usage getToolUses();
}

enum TeacherUsage;
Teacher:public Person{}
TeacherTool: public Tool<TeacherUsage>{
 TeacherUsage getToolUses();
}
// etc Lawyer
```

Next, we want `Teachers` to only ever use `TeacherTools`, not `LawyerTools`, so we extend the template a little further:

```
template <class Usage>
Person{
 Tool<Usage> *Tools[];
}

template <class Usage>
Tool{
 virtual Usage getToolUses();
}

Teacher:public Person<TeacherUsage>{}

TeacherTool: public Tool<TeacherUsage>{
 TeacherUsage getToolUses();
}
// etc Lawyer
```

And it makes sense that the `enum TeacherUsage` should be `enum Teacher::Usage`, so we go:

```
template <class Usage>
Person{
 Tool<Usage> *Tools[];
}

template <class Usage>
Tool{
 virtual Usage getToolUses();
}

Teacher:public Person<Teacher::Usage>{
  enum Usage;
}

TeacherTool: public Tool<Teacher::Usage>{
 TeacherUsage getToolUses();
}
// etc Lawyer
```

However, this won't work, because `Teacher::Usage` for the template parameter in the declaration of `Teacher` hasn't been declared yet.

Is there any way I could partially forward declare `Teacher::Usage` so I can use it in my template for `Teacher`?

Comment: I assume that the code you show is only pseudo-code, considering that it's not valid C++ in a few ways (unrelated to the problem you're asking about).

Comment: Yeah. I hope it gets the point across.

Comment: In your code there is no relationship between `Usage` and `TeacherUsage`. You can't override a virtual function with a mismatching signature. In the end `Teacher` will derive from `Person<TeacherUsage>` and `Lawyer` from `Person<LawyerUsage>`, which are two different classes with no relationship.

Comment: Yeah ok im comfortable with that. I'm more concerned about being able to forward declare Teacher::Usage so I can use it as a template paramter in Teacher<Teacher::Usage>.